# How to remove &nbsp; from inside tags, inside a string

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm outputting a huge string which is created by a WYSIWYG editor. The following is an example of an output that the editor makes. I'm trying to prevent all the spaces created by the `&nbsp`'s from the beginning and end (inside each tag), so that the tags tightly wrap the content. Rtrim and Ltrim don't work because they trim the whole string, not the tags inside it.

Here is an example of a string.

```
<div>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Small&nbsp;amount of text, should be&nbsp;alot.</div>
<div>Small&nbsp;amount of text, should be&nbsp;alot. &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </div>
```

This will output something along the lines of the following (the div has been left in to show the extent of the spaces, but would be hidden on output.)

```
<div>   Small amount of text, should be alot.</div>
<div>Small amount of text, should be alot.   </div>
```

I would prefer this out output..

```
<div>Small amount of text, should be alot.</div>
<div>Small amount of text, should be alot.</div>
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Give an example of the string and the desired transformation.

Comment: The **best** way to do this would be to parse the document using SimpleXML or DOMDocument etc, trim the contents of the tags then reassemble the document again. You want to avoid using regex here!!! (someone is bound to suggest it)

Comment: do you want remove also &nbsp;?

Comment: @AbraCadaver Sure one sec. The string is the 'code snippet', but i'll make that a little more obvious.

Comment: That was my point.  &nbsp; is not whitespace. It appears as whitespace when rendered as HTML.

Comment: @AbraCadaver That is my mistake, i meant &nbsp;. Will update this too

Comment: @AbraCadaver I've updated to better reflect the question.

Comment: @scrowler I'll Google these, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace repetitions of spaces and/or `&nbsp;` with a single `&nbsp`:

```
preg_replace('/(?:&nbsp;| ){2,}/', '&nbsp;', $string);
```

If you want to convert all `&nbsp;` to spaces, and then collapse the spaces then:

```
preg_replace('/ {2,}/', ' ', str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $string));
```

Note that this is not going to remove single spaces from after the opening tag, or before the closing tag. For something like that you're getting into some pretty nasty territory with regular expressions and you'll want to parse the document using DOM or XML instead.

However, leading and trailing whitespace is generally insignificant in HTML, so this should get you where you're going.

Comment: scrowler who replied via the comments, said that Regex is a bad idea?

Comment: @user2950370, which html tags will be in output (are all allowed)?

Comment: @user2950370 most times, yes. I was just writing an edit on that when you commented. So long as you're only interested in collapsing whitespace the regex *should* be fine. If you need to deal explicitly with "something inside tag `<x> </x>`" then you should be looking at DOM/XML instead.

Comment: @user2950370 this example is OK, he's not parsing the actual code but rather just sorting out repetitions of `&nbsp;`s

Comment: My understanding of whitespace vs &nbsp; was a little mixed. Your second code snippet worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your final goal is:

1. replace `&nbsp;` with " "
2. squeeze whitespaces
3. remove trailing and leading whitechars inside tags,

you can achieve that by:

```
//1 replace hard spaces with spaces
$text = str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $text);
//2 squeeze spaces
$text = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $text);
//replace "> " & " <" with ">" & "<" respectively
$result = str_replace(array('> ', ' <'), array('>', '<'), $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not trying replacing the string?

```
$newStr = str_replace("&nbsp;", "", $oldStr);
```

Comment: Thanks for edit. Stackoverflow Android app is useless in writing code on the fly.